# Upload a file to Object Store without needing to store the file on local tomcat server

Tags: java, spring-boot, multithreading, multipartform-data

I have a rest end point that accepts a file as an input which is currently a multipart file, and since this is a multipart file this file is first stored on a temp location on the tomcat server and then we read this file from this temp location and then deploy it to the object store.

1. I want to change this implementation so that we no longer need to store this file in temp location on tomcat .
2. Since the file size is going to be huge in my case that is above 50MB for sure I need this operation to be performed asynchronously.

Any suggestion from the community on how I can achieve this.

So far I have tried `HttpServletRequest` and then from this request I have extracted the InputStream and synchronously I am able to deploy the file to object store .